# How to install heirloom-mailx on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, apt, mailx

I want to install heirloom-mailx on Ubuntu 14.04

My current `/etc/apt/sources.list` reads like this:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted    
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted    
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted    
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted    
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted
```

And `apt-get` is unable to find heirloom-mailx with this `sources.list`

What changes do I need to find heirloom-mailx?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have the following line in your `sources.list`:

```
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main universe
```

Then run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install heirloom-mailx
```